# Terraform provisioner trigger only for new instances / only run once

Tags: terraform

I have conditional provision steps I want to run for all compute instances created, but **only run once.**

I know I can put the provisioning within the compute resource, but then it cannot be conditional.
If I put it in a `null_resource`, I need a trigger, and I don't know how to trigger on only the newly created resources (i.e. if I already have 1 instance, and want to scale to 2, I want to only run provisioning on the 2nd being created, not run again on the 1st which is already provisioned).

How can I get a variable that only gives me the id or ip of the instance just created, as opposed to all of them?

Below an example of the provisioner.

```
resource "null_resource" "provisioning" {
  count = var.condition ? length(var.instance_ips) : 0

  triggers = {
    instance_ids = join(",", var.instance_ips)
  }

  connection {
    agent = false
    timeout = "4m"
    host = var.instance_ips[count.index]
    user = "user"
    private_key = var.ssh_private_key
  }

  provisioner "remote-exec" {
    inline = [ do something, then remove the public key from authorized_keys ]
  }
}
```

PS: the reason I only can run once (as opposed to run again and do nothing if already provisioned) is that I want to destroy the provisioning public key after I'm done, since it is using a tf generated key pair and the private key ends up in the state file, I want to make sure someone who gets access to the key pair still cannot access the instance.
Once the public key is removed from the `authorized_keys` the provisioner running a second time will just fail to connect, timeout and fail.
I found that I can use the `on_failure: continue` key, but then if it actual fails for legitimate reasons it would continue too.

I also could use a key pair that is generated locally with a `local-exec` provisioner so it doesn't show in the state file, but then the key is a file, which is not much different if someone get access to it; the file needs to stay on the machine, which may not work well with a cloud resource manager env that is recreated on a need to run basis.

And then I'm sure there are other ways to provision a file or script, but in this case it contains instance dependency data generated by TF, that I don't want left in a cloud-init.

So, I come down to needing to figure a way to use a `trigger` that only contains the new instance(s)

Any ideas how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

https://www.terraform.io/docs/provisioners/

This documentation lists provisioners as a `last resource` and provides some suggestions on how to avoid having to use it, for various common resources.

Execute the script from the `user_data`, which is specifically designed for provisional, run-once actions. Since defining the user_data supports all regular Terraform interpolation, you can use that opportunity to pass environment variables or selectively include/exclude parts of a script, if you need conditional logic.

The downside is that any change in `user_data` results in recreating the instances, or creating a new launch configuration/template.

Comment: User_data ends up in the cloud-init script which i mentioned i don't want because of the sensitivity of the data. Plus as you say changes in the user-data means destroying instances, which is fine if the data changes, but not what i'm asking here.